# Qt C++ Initialization List Confusion

Tags: c++, qt, initialization-list

I'm getting started with Qt (and C++, to a lesser extent), and I wanted to be sure I fully understood the base code before continuing on. I understand that the first element in the initialization list is being used to select a non-default inherited constructor.

What is the purpose of ui(new Ui::TestAppMain), though? It seems to me like it would be an infinite loop, since ui is being set to a new instance of TestAppMain in the constructor, but that's not the case.

```
namespace Ui {
    class TestAppMain;
}

class TestAppMain : public QMainWindow{
    public:
        explicit TestAppMain(QWidget *parent = 0);

    private:
        Ui::TestAppMain *ui;
};

TestAppMain::TestAppMain(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::TestAppMain){
    ui->setupUi(this);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

`Ui::TestAppMain` is not the same as your `TestAppMain` class. It's another C++ class that is generated by Qt from the .ui file you've created in Qt Creator. To avoid confusion and naming conflicts, Qt puts all such generated classes in the `Ui` namespace.

It is a standard Qt practice to include an instance of `Ui::MyWidget` in your own class `MyWidget`. In your case, after you instantiate `Ui::TestAppMain`, you use that object to initialize your main window (represented by your `TestAppMain` class) according to the layout you've specified in TestAppMain.ui. That is done by calling `ui->setupUi(this)`.